# How to position a linerenderer and gameobject both on the bottom right of the screen in front of everything else?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The main goal is to make something easy as most as possible that i will be able to display in my game a save game progress indicator a drawn circle with animated object inside.

The first screenshot show in the game view how it should be like almost how it should be like but when i tried to use this prefab in my other project the linerenderer circle and the object was not even close to the bottom right position of the screen.

In one project i created my own saving progress indicator.
I'm drawing a circle with linerenderer and inside the circle position object.
I had to drag and move the linerenderer circle to position it on the right bottom corner and then the object inside to move it also to be in the circle but when i'm looking at the scene view the object is not inside the circle at all.

Also the object inside the drawn circle is not facing forward even if i rotated it on the y by 180 degrees.

When i drag the parent object or the linerenderer the object inside left behind not moving with the circle at the same time so i need all the time to move first the circle then the object again.

How can i make the object to be stick stay inside the drawn circle ? Like it was "image" or something.

[image: Parent empty gameobject position]

[image: LineRenderer object position]

[image: The object that should be inside the drawn circle]

When i'm dragging the parent empty gameobject the object inside the drawn circle lose his position inside the circle :

[image: object inside ddrawn circle lose position]

I tried this script attached to the parent empty gameobject but my main camera is used with cinemachine cameras all my scene is based on cinemachine cameras views.

This script didn't do anything.

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 
 public class ObjectInFrontOfCamera : MonoBehaviour {
     
     public GameObject objectTarget;
     public Vector3 screenPosition = new Vector3(0,0,20);
     
     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         
         if(objectTarget != null)
     {
         objectTarget.transform.position = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition);
     }
     
     }
 }
```